# how to set width and height in css in image class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the width and height of my img picture in CSS but it doesn't work in my CSS. The only way that I could do this in my img tag in my other file. I have done the following but can't get it to work:

```
img.whiteboard1 {
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
}
```

Comment: what is whiteboad1 here? Is it a file name?

Comment: Show the HTML too...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the word img, as shown below.

```
.whiteboard1 {
width: 10em;
height: 10em;
```

}

Comment: My apologies... I got it to work... just wrote the code under my media query instead of desktop...

Comment: but i got another problem now... when I changed the font-size of my textarea, I am also changing the width and height... how can I change the font size without chaning the width and height?

Comment: Can you please provide the html code. To be able to visualize what exactly is the problem.

Comment: thanks... I think i was just interpreting my textarea incorrectly and it is working now... cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you need to know that `<img>` is an inline element. Inline element can not use the `height` and `width` properties. If you really want to set the `height` and `width` to `<img>`, set the `display: inline-block` to the `<img>`

```
img.whiteboard1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
}
```